# Chef git resource doesn't download but says "up to date"

Tags: git, chef-infra

Here is my Chef code

```
git "/usr/local" do
  repository "https://github.internal.com/TOTC/maven-install.git"
  revision 'master'
  action :sync
  #notifies :run, "execute[unpack_maven]"
end

git "/opt/chef/cache" do
  repository "https://github.kdc.internal.com/TOTC/Python_Install.git" 
  revision 'master'
  action :sync
  #notifies :run, "execute[unpack_python]"
end
```

when either of these run it says..,

```
git[/opt/chef/cache] action checkout (up to date)
execute[unpack_python] action runsh: line 0: cd: /opt/chef/cache/Python_Install/: No such file or directory
```

It seems to think it's up to date and synced up with the master repository but when I look for the folder it doesn't exist.

Has anyone seen this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

So a few issues. The first and foremost is that the path you give to a git resource isn't like the `git clone` command. It doesn't create `/usr/local/maven-install`. You are telling it to overwrite all of `/usr/local` with the git repo, which seems unlikely to be your goal. Second is that you probably don't have `action :nothing` on the execute resources, add that.